# Redirect to a page when router link does not exist in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, routes, navigation, vuex, vue-router

Router links have been defined like:

```
const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: () => import('../views/Home.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: () => import('../views/About.vue')
  }
]
```

when links other than the defined ones are called like `'/contact'`, have to redirect it to `'/'`. Is there a way other than navigation guards like we use `.otherwise` in angular routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add  `{path: '*', component: () => import('../views/PageNotFound.vue')}` in the routconfig array, where  `PageNotFound`is just another component. You can add anything stuff you like in the PageNotFound component or name it to something else. Add it as last element in the array